# semantically correct way to map over a Map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS `Map` of objects that I want to iterate over without changing the Map (only using side effects).
What is the semantically right way to do this?
Solutions that I thought of:

```
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    // do something
});
```

(looks good but is not semantically correct IMHO as one should use map for operations that don't change the data structure iterated over (?))

```
[... myMap].map(([key, value]) => {
    // do something
});
```

(not as readable as forEach but semantically more correct (?))

```
for ([key, value] of myMap){
    // do something
}
```

(probably the best solution readability wise but same semantic concerns as with forEach)

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: “one should use map for operations that don't change the data structure iterated over (?)” is not true. `map` is for creating a new sequence of values. Feel free to use `forEach`.

Comment: @Ryan Ah, okay, thank you, I misunderstood something then.

Comment: @Ryan *"Feel free to use `forEach`"* - OP says that he wants to iterate over Map without mutating it, while `forEach` will surely mutate. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Kinduser I thought `forEach` _can_ mutate and because of that one should use `map` if not mutation is intended.

Comment: @Kinduser: No, `forEach` does not mutate the map.

Comment: @Ryan It doesn't return anything either, what's the point of using it then?

Comment: @Kinduser: I think you might be confusing “doesn’t mutate the map” with “can produce side-effects”. (Anything can produce side-effects in JavaScript, because it’s not a pure functional programming language.)

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can **only** iterate over a `map` (`const map = new Map()`) with `forEach`. `map`, `filter` and `reduce` are only available on arrays. It is not a question of semantics in this case.

Of course you have the choice of  the `for...of` loop as well, but these two do different things. I would not think of them as interchangeable.

```js
const map = new Map([
  [ 1, 'a' ],
  [ 2, 'b' ],
  [ 3, 'c' ],
]);

map.forEach((element, i) => console.log(element, i));
// a 1
// b 2
// c 3

for (const a of map) {
  console.log(a);
}

// [ 1, 'a' ]
// [ 2, 'b' ]
// [ 3, 'c' ]
```

Comment: All right, the more readable syntax convinces me.
Kudos to @Ryan also for pointing out my `map` misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I get what your question exactly is..

For immutability, you would properly always go for return a new array of objects. But it really comes down to what your needs is.

If you need a subset then `filter(..)` is you need; if it's a projection of the array's data, it's a `map(..)`. If a entirely new structure is needed you would use a classic map-reduce/reduce, `reduce(..)`.

Remember that if you have complex objects in the array, you still are returning the same objects in the new array. Only the array itself is new:

```
const x = [{a:1},{b:1}];
const y = x.map(e => e);
y[0].a++;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);

// [ { a: 2 }, { b: 1 } ]
// [ { a: 2 }, { b: 1 } ]
```